# Nativescript nested RadListView does not render on iOS 13

Tags: nativescript, radlistview

In my NS Core 6.3 app, I have nested RadListViews to display related items.  The outer RadListView displays properly, but the nested one does not display at all.  Here is my code:

```
<GridLayout row="1" rows="*" columns="*">
    <lv:RadListView items="{{ asks }}">
        <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                ...

                <GridLayout rows="*" columns="auto" marginTop="10">

                    <lv:RadListView items="{{ recs }}">
                        <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
                            <lv:ListViewLinearLayout scrollDirection="Horizontal" />
                        </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
                        <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
                            ...
                        </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
                    </lv:RadListView>
                </GridLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
    </lv:RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

If I replace the inner RadListView with a Repeater, the items render, but I cannot scroll through them horizontally.

Note that this code works as expected on Android.

Am I missing a setting or something?

Thank you.

Comment: You are not suppose to nest RadListView or ListView, simply they were not meant for that purpose. You may try the [nativescript-accordion](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-accordion) for this purpose. But it's vertical, for horizontal you may have to tweak the original implementation. Otherwise Repeater with a ScrollView is still a better workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different combinations between RadListView, ListView, and Repeater, but I could not make this work.  So, for the inner list, I ended up using https://github.com/manijak/nativescript-carousel.